# Windows RT UpgradeToSslAsync( ..)is failing if there is a Proxy server in between?

Tags: tcp, proxy, windows-runtime, windows-rt

I m trying to implement the following scenario in WinRT in c++ ,

> Client----TLS -------proxy------TLS------->RemoteTLSserver

So,I did make a TCP connection with proxy,Then send a HTTP connect request for Remote TLS server. And I am successful to do it:

> Client------TCP---------->proxy---------TCP(forwarding)------>Remote TLS server.

Then I use UpgradeToSslAsync(SocketProtectionLevel::Tls10,validationHostName)

(here I use my TLS server HostName as validation host).

I am getting an Exception: `The token supplied to the function is invalid`

**Note:** `UpgradeToSslAsync()` works with my TLS server if there is no proxy in between.

**Is it possible in Windows RT to relay data through proxy server in TLS protocol?**

Comment: [Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865) traces from your server would help :)

Comment: I got the root cause of the failure.There is two major problem while upgrading a socket after send and recv some data.first one is- u cant run a recursive loop for receiving data if u want to upgrade the sokcet in later.This will get I/O exception while upgrading.And 2nd problem is that socket up gradation will  fail if there are some data in the sockets buffer.U have to load and read all the data from the buffer.So,I solved this problem by reading all the data(not in recursive loop)from socket buffer before calling upgrade operation.